# python3 conversion between cvxopt.matrix and numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x

python: python3.2
cvxopt: 1.1.5
numpy: 1.6.1

I read http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/examples/tutorial/numpy.html

```
import cvxopt
import numpy as np
cvxopt.matrix(np.array([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]))
```

I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: non-numeric element in list
```

By `np.array(cvxopt.matrix([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]))`, I got

```
array([[b'\x07', b'\n'],
   [b'\x08', b'\x0b'],
   [b'\t', b'\x0c']], 
  dtype='|S8')
```

Comment: I think it is a bug. Your code works fine with python 2.7 (as stated in the tutorial you mention). I recommend you to ask to the cvxopt discussion forum (http://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/cvxopt).

Comment: You could try to force a `dtype=float` when invoking `numpy.array`..

Comment: @PierreGM Just tried. Didn't work :-( .

Answer (score 4):

As of `cvxopt == 1.2.6` and `numpy == 1.21.2`:

```py
import cvxopt
import numpy as np

matrix = cvxopt.matrix(np.array([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]))
print(matrix)
```

produces the output:

```
[  7   8   9]
[ 10  11  12]
```

and `print(repr(matrix))` says:

```
<2x3 matrix, tc='i'>
```

and `print(type(matrix))` says:

```
<class 'cvxopt.base.matrix'>
```

The resulting matrix has integer type ([the `'i'`](https://cvxopt.org/userguide/matrices.html#dense-matrices)) because the starting `numpy` array contained integers. Starting with `double` results in a `'d'` type.

Answer (score 2):

Check the patched dense.c that I put up on the cvxopt discussion forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cvxopt/9jWnkbJvk54).  Recompile with this, and you will be able to convert np arrays to dense matrices.  I assume the same kind of edits will be necessary for sparse matrices, but as I do not need them I will leave that up to the devs.

Comment: The patched dense.c only works when converting from numpy.array to cvxopt.matrix, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not fixed, a simple workaround for

```
cvxopt.matrix(nparray)
```

is

```
cvxopt.matrix(nparray.T.tolist())
```

It is more tough for the opposite direction. If you expect int array,

```
np.vectorize(lambda x: int.from_bytes(x, 'big'))(np.array(cvxoptmat).T)
```

For the double array:

```
import struct
np.vectorize(lambda x: struct.unpack('d', x))(np.array(cvxoptmat).T)
```