# converting numpy vector to cvxopt

Tags: python, numpy, cvxopt

This may be a very silly question, but I have been struggling with it and couldn't find it readily in the documentation.

I am trying to do a quadratic programming using the [description given here](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#quadratic-programming). The [documentation here](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/matrices.html#c-matrices) covers only conversion of 2 dimensional numpy arrays into cvxopt arrays, not 1 dimensional numpy arrays.

My `q` vector of the objective function `(1/2)x' P x + q' x` is a numpy vector, say of size `n`.

I tried to convert `q` from numpy to cvxopt in the following ways:

```
import cvxopt as cvx
cvx_q = cvx.matrix(q)   # didn't work
cvx_q = cvx.matrix(q, (n, 1)) # didn't work
cvx_q = cvx.matrix(np.array([q])) # didn't work
cvx_q = cvx.matrix(np.array([q]), (1, n)) # didn't work
cvx_q = cvx.matrix(np.array([q]), (n, 1)) # didn't work
```

In all cases, I get an answer `TypeError: buffer format not supported`.

However, numpy matrices seem to work fine, e.g.

```
cvx_p = cvx.matrix(p)   # works fine, p is a n x n numpy matrix
```

If I try to run the optimization without converting the numpy vector to cvxopt format like this:

```
cvxs.qp(cvx_p, cvx_q, cvx_g, cvx_h, cvx_a, cvx_b)
```

I get an error: `TypeError 'q' must be a 'd' matrix with one column`.

What could be the correct way to convert a numpy vector into a cvxopt matrix with one column?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551009/python3-conversion-between-cvxopt-matrix-and-numpy-array/45933678#45933678

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not included any sample data, but when I encountered this error, it was because of the dtype.

try:

```
q = q.astype(np.double)
cvx_q = matrix(q)
```

CVX only accepts doubles, not ints.

Comment: Strictly speaking it is the `cvxopt.qp` solver that requires double floats for all of its arguments. CVXOPT itself does support integer matrices (`cvxopt.matrix(np.arange(5))` will return an integer matrix with typecode `'i'`).

Answer (score 0):

One of the key mistakes is your assumption that CVX accepts int, which is incorrect. CVX accepts only double. So, the right way of doing it maybe:

```
import cvxopt as cp
if not isinstance(q, np.double): 
  q.astype(np.double)
cvx_q = cp.matrix(q)
```